# How do I pop the [List] after reading the JSON URL?

Tags: python, json

I need to have this answered

Write a Python program that reads the JSON data found at https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

```js
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
    "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"
  },
  ...
  {
    "userId": 4,
    "id": 38,
    "title": "explicabo et eos deleniti nostrum ab id repellendus",
    "body": "animi esse sit aut sit nesciunt assumenda eum voluptas\nquia voluptatibus provident quia necessitatibus ea\nrerum repudiandae quia voluptatem delectus fugit aut id quia\nratione optio eos iusto veniam iure"
  },
  ...
  {
    "userId": 10,
    "id": 100,
    "title": "at nam consequatur ea labore ea harum",
    "body": "cupiditate quo est a modi nesciunt soluta\nipsa voluptas error itaque dicta in\nautem qui minus magnam et distinctio eum\naccusamus ratione error aut"
  }
]
```

Then loop through the posts and delete (pop out) any posts made by the user with a userId of 5.

Write the resulting JSON (with posts deleted) to a local file.

So far I have this,

```
import json
import urllib.request

url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode()

site_info =json.loads(data)

for info in site_info:
    print("{}, {}, {}, {}".format(
        info["userId"], info["id"], info["title"], info["body"]))

mylist= [{"userId":1},{"userId":2},{"userId":3},{"userId":4},{"userId":5}, 
         {"userId":6},{"userId":7},{"userId":8},{"userId":9},{"userId":10}]

for i in (5,0):
    print(i)
    if mylist[i]["userId"] == 5:
        mylist.pop(i)

print (mylist)
```

Comment: Usually, the best way to do this is to create a new list, and copy over the elements you DON'T want to delete.

Comment: So create two lists?

Comment: No, replace the first list.  See my answer below.

Comment: Giving me the error that mylist is not defined?

Comment: Have you looked at my answer?  That code works.

Comment: Yes! It does work for the user Id but I believe what I have to do is have the Data from the URL that have the User ID of 5 to be gone, not just pulled from that small list. Does that make sense? So it pulls the url data, and anything that has the userID of 5 will not be pulled.

Comment: I would have hoped that you could extend my answer to your case.  All you have to do is change "mylist" to "info" in the list comprehension.

Comment: So Im getting this result [{'userId': 1}, {'userId': 2}, {'userId': 3}, {'userId': 4}, {'userId': 6}, {'userId': 7}, {'userId': 8}, {'userId': 9}, {'userId': 10}]. But this is still showing 5, 42, commodi ullam sint et excepturi error explicabo praesentium voluptas, odio fugit voluptatum ducimus earum autem est incidunt voluptatem
odit reiciendis aliquam sunt sequi nulla dolorem
non facere repellendus voluptates quia
ratione harum vitae ut

Comment: Where do you see 5 in that list?

Comment: In the URL page that is being taken down, it is still showing the information with the userID 5.  For Example.. UserID 5, 42, commodi ullam sint et excepturi error explicabo praesentium voluptas, odio fugit voluptatum ducimus earum autem est incidunt voluptatem odit reiciendis aliquam sunt sequi nulla dolorem non facere repellendus voluptates quia ratione harum vitae ut

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're doing with my code, since you haven't posted any updates, but it works perfectly well.  Here I am processing the received JSON, and you can see the output has nothing from user 5.

```
import json
import urllib.request

url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode()
site_info =json.loads(data)

non5 = [post for post in site_info if post['userId'] != 5]

print(json.dumps(non5))
```

Comment: Ah! Okay now that is giving me the correct results. I really appreciate your help, I don't mean to sound ungrateful. The one last problem here for me though is that I have to use the POP method. Can we edit this somehow to create the POP? I know this is doing the same thing but...

Comment: for i in range(len(mylist2)-1, -1, -1):
   print(i)
   if mylist2[i]["a"]==2:
      mylist2.pop(i)

print(mylist2)

Comment: That was the example given to us to use as a replica

Comment: That will more or less work, but `pop` is just the wrong way to do this.  When you `pop` an element, all elements following have to be moved in memory.  And it's a very bad habit to modify a list or dict that you are iterating through.

Comment: I understand it may not be the best way to do it, but I kind of have to use that way just to show that I understand the concept. How could I reword your given code to give the same output but look like what I sent? I am confused when it comes to the -1 -1 -1 segment

Comment: Do you understand that `range(len(mylist2)-1,-1,-1)` counts backwards from 1 less than the length of the list down to 0?

Comment: Yes but how would that method make the userId 5 pop then? I understand it counts backwards,  but what does counting down have to do with popping? and also what do the 2nd and 3rd -1 do?

Comment: You would say `if mylist2[i]["userId"] == 5` to search for that user id, of course.  The second "-1" says the range ends at -1.  The third "-1" says the range goes down by one, instead of up.  `range(5)` produces `0,1,2,3,4`.  `range(5,-1,-1)` produces `5,4,3,2,1,0`.

Comment: Ohh now that makes sense! I could use == 5,-1,-1 then?